# How can update a JdbcRowSet object?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to execute the following SQL command with one JdbcRowSet object:

> INSERT INTO Authors (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('Sue', 'Smith')

I know that i can execute with Connection and Satements objects, but i want to do this with the interface JdbcRowSet, because  one JdbcRowSet object is updatable and scrollable by default.

My code is:

```
public class JdbcRowSetTest
{
    public static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/books";
    public static final String USERNAME = "Ezazel";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "Ezazel";

    public JdbcRowSetTest()
    {
        try
        {
            JdbcRowSet rowSet = new JdbcRowSetImpl();
            rowSet.setUrl( DATABASE_URL );
            rowSet.setUsername( USERNAME );
            rowSet.setPassword( PASSWORD );
            rowSet.setCommand( "INSERT INTO Authors (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('Sue', 'Smith')" );
            rowSet.execute();
        }
        catch( SQLException e )
        {
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        JdbcRowSetTest app = new JdbcRowSetTest ();
    }
}
```

SQLException error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1086)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkForDml(StatementImpl.java:502)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2224)
    at com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl.execute(JdbcRowSetImpl.java:582)
    at JdbcRowSetTest.(JdbcRowSetTest.java:23)
    at JdbcRowSetTest.main(JdbcRowSetTest.java:53)
```

Comment: You are swallowing exceptions. Please check if it doesn't throw an exception and provides us with the stacktrace.

Comment: SQLException error: java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

Comment: I hadn't even noticed it before, but `setCommand` is for the **select** query necessary to populate the rowset. The way you currently use it doesn't make sense. Updating/inserting a rowset is exactly the same as you would with a (updatable) `ResultSet`. The javadoc of both also include examples (you might want to check `CachedRowSet` as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a `JdbcRowSet` to execute insert statements like that. If that is what you want, then you should use a normal `Statement` or `PreparedStatement` instead.

The [`RowSet.setCommand`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSet.html#setCommand-java.lang.String-) is for queries only:

> Sets this `RowSet` object's command property to the given SQL query. This property is optional when a rowset gets its data from a data source that does not support commands, such as a spreadsheet.
>   **Parameters:**
>   `cmd` - the SQL query that will be used to get the data for this RowSet object; may be null

If you really want to use a row set, then you can update or insert new rows in the way documented for an updatable [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

Updating:

> to update a column value in the current row. In a scrollable `ResultSet`
>   object, the cursor can be moved backwards and forwards, to an absolute
>   position, or to a position relative to the current row. The following
>   code fragment updates the `NAME` column in the fifth row of the
>   `ResultSet` object `rs` and then uses the method `updateRow` to update the
>   data source table from which `rs` was derived.
>
> ```
> rs.absolute(5); // moves the cursor to the fifth row of rs
> rs.updateString("NAME", "AINSWORTH"); // updates the
> // NAME column of row 5 to be AINSWORTH
> rs.updateRow(); // updates the row in the data source
> ```

For inserting:

> to insert column values into the insert row. An updatable `ResultSet`
>   object has a special row associated with it that serves as a staging
>   area for building a row to be inserted. The following code fragment
>   moves the cursor to the insert row, builds a three-column row, and
>   inserts it into rs and into the data source table using the method
>   `insertRow`.
>
> ```
> rs.moveToInsertRow(); // moves cursor to the insert row
> rs.updateString(1, "AINSWORTH"); // updates the
> // first column of the insert row to be AINSWORTH
> rs.updateInt(2,35); // updates the second column to be 35
> rs.updateBoolean(3, true); // updates the third column to true
> rs.insertRow();
> rs.moveToCurrentRow();
> ```

Note that the reference implementation of `javax.sql.rowset` in my experience regularly doesn't work as expected. You might be better off using plain JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing **`execute()`**:

To query using *"Select"* statement and return a JdbcRowSet:

```
public void createJdbcRowSet(String url, String username, String password, String sql) {
    jdbcRs = new JdbcRowSetImpl();
    jdbcRs.setCommand(sql);
    jdbcRs.setUrl(url);
    jdbcRs.setUsername(username);
    jdbcRs.setPassword(password);
    jdbcRs.execute();
    // ...
}
```

**Update:**
Once you have the returned JdbcRowSet, you can insert a new row as this example shows:

```
public void updateJdbcRowSet(String username, String password) {
    jdbcRs.moveToInsertRow();
    jdbcRs.updateString("USERNAME", "NewUser");
    jdbcRs.updateString("PASSWORD", "ENCRYPTED");
    jdbcRs.insertRow();
}
```

Comment: @Ezazel It works. add `e.printStackTrace()` to your catch block and see you what error you encounter

Comment: SQLException error: java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            RowSetFactory rowset =RowSetProvider.newFactory();
            JdbcRowSet jdbcrow=rowset.createJdbcRowSet();
            jdbcrow.setUrl(BD_Url);
            jdbcrow.setUsername(DB_User);   
            jdbcrow.setPassword(DB_password);
//this is your database connectivity like uername,password and url and
 driver in not imp in mysql 5.1.23 jar file 

            jdbcrow.setCommand("Select * from Demo");
            jdbcrow.execute();
//uppere parts is use to fetch the record from table



   System.out.println("--------------------Insert----------");
    jdbcrow.moveToInsertRow();
    jdbcrow.updateInt("ID", 115);
    jdbcrow.updateString("Username","Hitesh");
    jdbcrow.updateString("Password","Sir");
    jdbcrow.insertRow();
```

//The down code is used for  update the value

```
System.out.println("=--------------------Update-------------------------");
jdbcrow.absolute(3);// 3rd row
jdbcrow.updateString("Password","Sirs" ); //colname password 
jdbcrow.updateRow();
```

For Delete you can use

```
System.out.println("=-----------Delete-----------------------------");



    while (jdbcrow.next()) {  
            String id=jdbcrow.getString("Id"); 
         //here i getting  ID  record from my table
          System.out.println("s"   +id);
            if(id.equals("102")) { 
            //then i my Specifying that if my table iD is .eqauls to 102 then delete 
              that record you also used this type to updatetbale

                 jdbcrow.deleteRow();
                System.out.println("gaye");
                break;
            }
        }
        //if record delete then preform `enter code here`some operation
```

//this is used to delete last record from table

```
System.out.println("=---------------delete-------------------------");
    jdbcrow.last();
    jdbcrow.deleteRow();
```

Comment: Please also add some explanational text, not just code.